# How to invalidate an iterator?

Tags: c++, stl

Since I know an iterator in the program could be invalidated by some previous operation, I want to invalidate it explicitly. Such as assign NULL to a pointer to invalidate it, I just want to do the same on iterator. `container.end()` could not be the precise idea here. I tried to assign NULL to my iterator, but it failed. How can I get the same behavior of NULL pointer on iterator?

Comment: First, I think it is not good idea to such behaviour. Second, you can store pointer to iterator.

Comment: if you really want someone may also explain how to get Undefined Behavior explicitely ;-)

Comment: Why would you want this? There's nothing you can do with the iterator afterwards that you couldn't do before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't this always work? (iterators are always assignable and default-constructible)

```
template <typename Iter>
void foo(Iter it){
  it = Iter(); // invalidate
}
```

Comment: This is very cool. I can get the iterator type directly, so the function is unnecessary. By the way, I think we need to pass `it` by reference, is this right?

Comment: in order to modify it, sure. This was just an example. The only reason I made it a function was that it was the easiest way to say "Assuming the iterator type is `Iter` and the iterator object is called `it`..." :)

Answer (score 4):

> could be invalidated by some previous operation, I want to invalidate it explicitly

... If you know it may not be valid, then all you have to do it **stop using it**. Invalidating the iterator explicitly accomplishes nothing, because using it is a programming error either way.

Comment: try to limit the scope of your iterator by using additional blocks. Outside the block, the iterator isn't there anymore. That's better than invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Why don´t You want to use `container.end()` ?... it works for most containers...

For std::string You may want to check , wether the position is `yourstring.npos`;

Answer (score 1):

You can't, in general. There are some iterators that cannot be invalidated at all. For instance, a random number generator can be modelled as an output iterator, with `operator*` returning the current number and `operator++` generating a new one.